# How do I resolve this error using Paths.of?

Tags: java

I have been trying many of the examples provided and have yet to be successful. Here is the code I am currently trying, but getting an error in Eclipse on Paths.of (the of is underlined in red) that says: "rename in file".

```java
String content; 

try {
    content = Files.readAllLines(Paths.of("C:", "Calcs.txt"));
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace ();
}
                
System.out.println (content);
```

Answer (score 1):

First it is not possible, if you get a list as return type, to assign this to a string. So you must write:

```java
List<String> content;
```

Second regarding to the [Java 8 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) there is no method `of` available for this class. You can use the method `get` like this:

```java
List<String> content = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:", "Calcs.txt"));
```

Otherwise there exists a [method `of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#of(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...)) in the Path class since Java 11. Therefore you can write something like that:

```java
List<String> content = Files.readAllLines(Path.of("C:", "Calcs.txt"));
```

Comment: I made the changes suggested. But, I am still getting an error in Eclipse telling me to change Path.get to Path.set.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your eclipse IDE? Which `Paths` class did you import? Is it the class in the package: `java.nio.file`?

Comment: List<String> content; 
    
try {
 content = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get ("C:", "Calcs.txt"));
} 
catch (IOException e1) {
 e1.printStackTrace ();
}
    
System.out.println (content);

Comment: I am including java.nio.file.Files.

Comment: I copy and paste your code in my IDE and it works for me?! Maybe it is helpful for me to get the complete code from you with all imports? Or I guess a screenshot could be helpful. But right now I am a little out of my depth. Did you import another library? The classes `Paths` and `Path` have no set method

Comment: Can you cleanup your project: `Project > Clean`? And if you use Maven or Gradle, please update/refresh the project.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [`Paths.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...)):

```java
String content; 
try {
    content = String.join("\n", Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/home/hassan", "Foo.java")));

} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace ();
}
```

Comment: When I tried Paths.get...Eclipse gives me an error that tells me to "change it to Paths.set".

Comment: What Java version are you using ?

Comment: I am using Java SE-11...JDK 12...Java Version 8 Update 181.

Comment: Hah, that was it. I had another library that had a Paths class buried in it. Got rid of it and all is good. Thanks!